# Center text horizontall in react native with flexbox

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have some react native code below.

```js
<View
    style={{
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <H3 style={{ marginVertical: 15 }}>Loren Ipsum</H3>
      <P2
        style={[
          {
            marginBottom: 20,
          },
        ]}
      >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      </P2>
      <P style={[{ marginBottom: 20 }, Styles.centerText]}>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
      </P>
</View>
```

Which looks like below

[image]

The `<P>` is suing `Styles.centerText` which is

```js
 centerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
```

And you can see the second line of the `<P>` is horizontally centered. How can I get the first `<P1>` to match what the style of the `<P>` i.e also horizontally center the second line of `<P1>`? The `<P1>` is a newer component from an internal design library that no longer takes in an `Styles.centerText` as a valid property.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that refers to `<P1>` or `<P2>` that you have in your markup? Why not just use `<P>` which allows `Styles.centerText` as a valid property?

Comment: we are trying to deprecate `<P>` because it comes from an older internal design library. The `<P1>` comes from an updated internal design library that we're trying to use moving forward.

Comment: You want to center text without using `textAlign: 'center'`?

Comment: @Abe correct. Is that possible? I'm pretty new to CSS

Comment: Anything is possible, but for something with such a simple existing solution, it would require a lot of effort.  For example, you could add one word of the line at a time until your width was exceeded, start a new line, and keep going like that. Then center those lines horizontally. But it would be best to just use the style that does that for you (and probably covers lots of edge cases I haven't thought of here)

Comment: Your new component should accept TextStyle props - it will make it difficult to use if it can't.